# Using variable in exiftool -if condition

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to reorganise images based on keywords that are found in the IPTC metadata. More specifically, I need sort images into directories based on the species name in the `subject` pseudo tag of `exiftool`.

To do this, I have compiled the keywords in a `.txt` file (species_ls.txt), with each keyword on a new line, as such:

`Asian Tortoise
Banded Civet
Banded Linsang
...`

To sort the images I have created the following for loop, which iterates through each line of the document, with `sed` pulling out the keyword. Here, `$line_no` is the number of lines in the `species_ls.txt` file, and `image_raw` is the directory containing the images.

```
for i in 'seq 1 $line_no'; do
    sp_name=$(sed -n "${i}p" < species_ls.txt)
    exiftool -r -if '$subject=~/${sp_name}/i' \
        '-Filename=./${sp_dir}/%f%+c%E' image_raw`
```

Although the for loop runs, no conditions are being met in the `-if` flag in `exiftool`. I am assuming this is because the variable `sp_name` is not being passed into the condition properly.

Any suggestions, or a better way of doing this, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the line with condition, rather than using single quotes (`' '`), it  would be better to use double quotes (`" "`).

The single quotes mean that the content is passed literally, meaning your variable won't get expanded.

To overcome, the $subject line expanding (which I presume you don't want), you can just put a `\` in front of the `$` to escape it being read as a variable.

This line should now look like:

```
exiftool -r -if "\$subject=~/${sp_name}/i"
```

Hope this helps you!